# spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec does not work

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Using spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0,
below are the settings

```
spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes=1,
spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec=0.001, (I also tried 0.01, 0.0001, 0.00001)
spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes=512
```

My understanding is each task should be limited to output **0.001 mb/s, around 1kb/s**.
However, median task output **820KB in 20 seconds**, which means **41kb/s**.

Does this mean the configuration is not working?

[image]

Comment: Did you get an explanation on this?

Comment: According to https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md, the name of the property should be `spark.cassandra.output.throughputMBPerSec`. But I'm also struggling with this...
Edit: in 2.4.0 it was `spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec`